# No matching function for call to 'QString::fromLatin1(QByteArray*&)'

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qbytearray

I have a class `A` that calls class `B` after a signal is emitted. When the user closes `B`, I am trying to transfer a `QString` value from `B` to `A`.  To do so, I first convert the `QString` to a `QByteArray`, then I am exchanging the `QByteArray` between classes. Finally, I am converting the `QByteArray` back into a `QString`.

However, during that second conversion, I get this error:

> no matching function for call to 'QString::fromLatin1(QByteArray*&)`

Below is my code.

`classB.h` (is where the first `QByteArray` is implemented):

```
public :
    QByteArray *byt = new QByteArray;
```

`classB.cpp`:

```
void classB::foo(QString userame, QString password)
{
    //Some other code
    QString usernameOfNewUser;
    usernameOfNewUser = userame;
    byt = usernameOfNewUser.toLocal8Bit();
    qWarning(byt->data());
}
```

`classA.h` (where that second `QByteArray` is implemented):

```
private:
    QByteArray *newUserArray = new QByteArray;
```

`classA.cpp` (where the problem is located):

```
classB *cUdsfqkjb =new classB();
cUdsfqkjb->show();
if(!cUdsfqkjb->isVisible())
{
    newUserArray = cUdsfqkjb->byt;
    QString newUser = QString::fromLatin1(newUserArray);
```

The error is located on the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fromLatin1()` method has the following signature:

```
QString fromLatin1(const char * str, int size = -1)
```

So you will need to pass the `QByteArray`'s data to the method like this:

```
QString newUser = QString::fromLatin1(newUserArray->constData(), newUserArray->count());
```

In Qt5, there is also this overload:

```
QString fromLatin1(const QByteArray &str)
```

So you can use this instead:

```
QString newUser = QString::fromLatin1(*newUserArray);
```

Comment: Must have missed that... I tried both ways, but now I get another error : `conversion from 'QByteArray' to 'QByteArray*' is ambiguous
     byt = usernameOfNewUser.toLocal8Bit();
         ^`. They both give me the same error. Do you happen to know where that comes from?

Comment: I managed to solve the second error (I just forgot adding the pointer's asterix `*`) Thank you for your answer.

Comment: `QByteArray toLocal8Bit() const`, so either make byt a QByteArray instead of pointer or write `*byt = usernameOfNewUser.toLocal8Bit()`